# Adding EditText with button with input later used to do addition

Tags: android, arrays, android-arrayadapter

I am confused that after adding more EditText field, how am i suppose to know the string code so i could do an addition math to add them all up.Thank You.

**Update :**
So I managed to use ArrayAdapter to add the data into an array but I am facing problem to call it back in. Help!!!

```
    txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.iteminput);
    show = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Add);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String getInput = txt.getText().toString();

            addArray.add(getInput);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Splitter.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addArray);
            show.setAdapter(adapter);
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.iteminput)).setText("");


        }
    });


   public void Calculate(View v){


    for(int i = 0; i<adapter.getCount() ; i++){
      Integer  Total= adapter.getItem(i);
    }
    TextView Total=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Total);
    Total.setText("Splitted Cost: "+Total.toString());

  }
```

**The getCount couldnt get the adaptor :(**

Comment: Describe clearly what you want to achieve

Comment: I wanted to make an app where user can input number into an array, after that there will be a calculate button where when onClick will ad all the number in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare your adapter as a field and you will be able to access it in a method.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; // declared as a field now you can access it anywhere.

    public void onCreate(){
         txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.iteminput);
    show = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Add);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String getInput = txt.getText().toString();

            addArray.add(getInput);
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Splitter.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addArray);
            show.setAdapter(adapter);
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.iteminput)).setText("");


        }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, it solved the calling part, but for the adding part this code couldnt work.     <br/>                                                                public void Calculate(View v){


        for(int i = 0; i<adapter.getCount() ; i++){
          String Total+= adapter.getItem(i);
        }
        TextView Total=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Total);
        Total.setText("Splitted Cost: "+Total.toString());

    }"